# What is the purpose of making Equals a common method?

Tags: c#, language-design

This is not a question how to implement it but what is the purpose of this method? I mean -- OK, I understand that is needed when searching, but why it is buried as an method of "object" class?

The story goes -- I have classes which objects are not comparable by default (in logical sense). Each time you want to compare/search for them you have to specify exactly how matching is done. The best in such case would be:

1. there is no such ubiquitous method as Equals, problem solved, no programmer (user of my class) would fall in trap by omitting custom match when searching

   but since I cannot change C#
2. hide inherited, unwanted methods to prevent the call (compile-time)

   but this also would require change to C#
3. override Equals and throw exception -- at least programmer is notified in runtime

So I am asking because I am forced to ugly (c), because (b) is not possible and because of lack of (a).

So in short -- what is the reason of forcing all objects to be comparable (Equals)? For me it is one assumption too far. Thank you in advance for enlightenment :-).

Answer (score 7):

I agree that it was basically a mistake, in both .NET and Java. The same is true for `GetHashCode` - along with every object having a monitor.

It made a *bit* more sense before generics, admittedly - but with generics, overriding `Equals(object)` always feels pretty horrible.

I [blogged about this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/12/05/redesigning-system-object-java-lang-object.aspx) a while ago - you may find both the post and the comments interesting.

Comment: Nice post! Never really put my finger on it, but indeed - out of tens of classes there may be one where I actually need equality semantics. In those cases it usually is an equality coming from the application specs. In the beginning .NET copied a number of things from JAVA. I wonder what the argument was to 'have' those things in the root of the inheritance tree, other than similarity to the antetype.

Comment: I think Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode are fine; any comparison methods for inheritable classes will generally have to be virtual, and the implementations for derived classes will have to type-check and type-cast their operands, so why not have a standardized 'patch-point' for equality testing? As for MemberwiseClone, having that as a protected method is the correct approach; my only problem with it is that since there isn't a commonly-accepted protocol for classes to hide protected members from subclasses, most classes don't hide MemberwiseClone from subclasses even though they should.

Comment: @supercat: You can have a single common interface to be implemented for equality testing. MemberwiseClone is a bit of an oddity, partly as it does magic under the hood. Would need to think about that one more carefully...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Using an interface would require either that base classes which use it use a virtual method to implement it, and define that as the 'patch point', or else that derived classes re-implement the equality interface.  If Animal were to define IEquatable in terms of virtual Equals/GetHashCode methods, but Dog were to re-implement the interface (even though it shouldn't), and Beagle were to override the Equals method defined in Animal, an attempt to compare two instances of Beagle would use the Dog comparison method.  Better to just have a single patch point.  Note that...

Comment: @supercat: I think this is getting too involved for a comment thread, to be honest. Equality with inheritance hierarchies is *fundamentally*  a messy business, IMO.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: ...it's perfectly meaningful to compare an Apple and an Orange for equality (though not for magnitude).  They are simply not equal.  Note also that if an equality relation on a non-sealed type is transitive, it cannot be generic.  If it's going to be possible to compare two Fruit objects, then the Equals method for an Apple must accept any Fruit, check whether it's an Apple, cast it if so, and do the comparison on that basis.  If the Equals methods are going to require type and casting, there's really not much advantage to generics.  As for MemberwiseClone...

Comment: @supercat: It depends on your equality criteria. It's meaningful to specify an equality comparer which can compare any two objects by volume, for example - in which case an apple and an orange may be equal. If you don't want generics, you can still have a non-generic `IEquatable` type which only deals in terms of objects - it still doesn't mean it has to be part of System.Object.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: ...putting it as a protected member of Object makes it possible for classes which shouldn't be cloned to make it inaccessible.  Were it not a member of Object, there'd be no nice way for classes to control whether or not they were cloneable.  Actually, there are a few other things that should perhaps also be protected members, like the ability to create a resurrection-tracking WeakReference, but that's another matter.  Care to chat sometime?

Comment: @supercat: As I said before, I think this is *way* too involved for a comment thread. Let's agree to disagree until we can discuss it in person some time...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I'm not in the UK.  Perhaps create a chat topic sometime?  BTW, how do you like my addendum to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838482/what-is-the-purpose-of-making-equals-a-common-method/7238775#7238775 ('equals' answers the question of whether a class promises that instance X is indistinguishable from instance Y without using ReferenceEquals or accessing their guts via non-public means.)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot option 4.: Do nothing, let the default reference equality take place. No big deal IMO. Even with your custom match options, you could choose a default option (I'd go for the most strict option) and use it to implement Equals().

Comment: No, I didn't forget this option. If programmer needs reference comparison, she/he should use reference comparison explicitly (ReferenceEquals). IOW -- say what you mean, don't take shortcuts.

Typing Equals instead of ReferenceEquals assuming they are equivalent is bad approach (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose someone has a List of Animal, and one wishes to compare two items against each other: an instance of Cat and an instance of Dog.  If the Cat instance is asked whether it is the same as the Dog instance, does it make more sense for the cat to throw an InvalidTypeException, or for it to simply say "No, it's not equal".

An Equals method is supposed to obey two rules:

1. Reciprocity of equality: For any X and Y, X.Equals(Y) will be true if and only if Y.Equals(X) is true.

   Liskov Substitution Principle: If class Q derives from P, an operation that can be done with a Q may also be done with a P.

These together imply that if Q derives from P, it must be possible for an object of type P to call Equals on an object of type Q, which in turn implies that it must be possible for an object of type Q to call Equals on an object of type P.  Further, if R also derives from P, it must be possible for an object of type Q to call Equals on an object of type R (whether or not R is related to Q).

While it may not be strictly necessary for all objects to implement Equals, it's much cleaner for all classes to have a single Equals(Object) than to have a variety of Equals methods for different base types, all of which must be overridden with identical semantics to avoid weird behaviors.

**Edit/Addendum**

Object.Equals exists to answer the question: given two object references X and Y, can object X promise that outside code which doesn't use ReferenceEquals, Reflection, etc. would be unable to show that X and Y do not refer to the same object instance?  For any object X, X.Equals(X) must be true since outside code cannot possibly show that X is not the same instance as X.  Further, if X.Equals(Y) is "legitimately" true, Y.Equals(X) must also be true; if not, the fact that X.Equals(X) (which is true) doesn't match Y.Equals(X) would be a demonstrable difference implying that X.Equals(Y) should be false.

For shallowly-mutable types, if X and Y refer to different object instances, one could generally demonstrate this by mutating X and observing whether the same mutation occurred in Y(*).  If such mutation could be used to demonstrate that X and Y are different object instances, then X.Equals(Y) should return true.  The reason two String objects containing the same characters will report themselves equal to each other is not just that they happen to contain the same characters at the time of comparison, but more significantly that if all instances of one were replaced with the other, only code that used ReferenceEquals, Reflection, or other such tricks, would even notice.

(*) It would be possible to have two distinct but indistinguishable instances X and Y of a shallowly-mutable class which both held references to each other, such that methods that would mutate one would also mutate the other.  If there would be no way for outside code to distinguish the instances apart, one might legitimately have X.Equals(Y) report true (and vice versa).  On the other hand, I can't think of any way such a class would be more useful that one in which both X and Y held immutable references to a shared mutable object.  Note that X.Equals(Y) does not require that X and Y to deep-immutable; it merely requires that any mutations applied to X will have identical effects on Y.

Comment: "While it may not be strictly necessary for all objects to implement Equals" -- and the question is exactly about this, not about properties of equality. I see no harm in having IEqual interface for those classes for which Equals makes sense. I have a lot of classes for which checking equality does not make sense, or at the moment of design and later usage introducing Equals is forced. IOW suppose I have class Something which should not be compared at all, only stored.

Comment: @macias: For what type of object could the one not answer the question of equality I posted in the edit above?  An object either promises that it will be indistinguishable from another, or it doesn't.

Comment: Where did you get part about two objects being indistinguishable other than via ReferenceEquals and Reflection? You seem to be stating this as an axiom - I disagree with it. For example, in C# 1.00m.Equals(1m) returns true, but they're distinguishable (just call ToString).

Comment: @Jon Skeet: My intention was to show that one could specify a useful behavior for Object.Equals that could be used to compare any object to any object, not to imply that all classes in fact implement Object.Equals in such a fashion. If you want to suggest that Equals/GetHashCode shouldn't be applied to all objects but without any consistent semantics, I'll agree with you.  I'll suggest, though, that the solution isn't to drop the "universal" Equals/GetHashCode methods, but rather to not have them overridden to mean something other than equivalence.

Comment: @supercat: I think we'll have to agree to disagree. In general, if something isn't consistently applicable to all subtypes, I wouldn't want it to be in the supertype.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: If one has a generalized means of testing for equivalence, then it will be possible to do things like object interning.  Suppose one wishes to have an array-like collection to hold 1,000,000 objects of type T, of which one expects there to be about 1,000 different ones and knows there will never be more than 65,535.  If one can test objects for equivalence, one could use a 1000-item Dictionary<T, Integer> to hold all the different instances, along with an array of about 1,000 T's, an array of about 1,000 reference counts, and an array of 1,000,000 shorts.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Such an array could be useful with all types that define equality as equivalence, but would be hard to create without some 'universal' equivalence-testing method.  Object equivalency is a concept applicable to *ALL* derivatives of object.  If someone derived a class from WaitHandle and overrode the Wait method to power down the computer, would that suggest that the base class's definition of WaitHandle.Wait was broken, or that the subtype's implementation was broken?

Comment: @supercat: You'd either constrain `T` to implement `IEquatable<T>`, or pass in an appropriate `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Generic IEquatable<T> is broken for inheritable classes.  One could define a non-generic IEquatable with semantics equivalent to overriding Equals/GetHashCode, but classes which override Equals to something other than equivalence would probably implement IEquatable the same way.  IEqualityComparer can't determine object equivalence without a standard way of asking objects.  I'll grant that Object shouldn't have a virtual Equals() method if you'll grant that it should have a virtual Equivalent() method.

Comment: @supercat: But whoever's building the dictionary should determine what equivalence to use if the object doesn't do it itself - and it can always fall back to reference equivalence. I don't think either of us is going to persuade the other...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I would like to chat sometime via the SO chat feature.  Perhaps I need to blog consistently (I have a couple blogs, but they're really dusty). I like writing much better, though, when I feel like I'm writing 'to' somebody. In any case, I can see significant uses for defining an equivalence relation such that (1) object instances which might behave differently must compare unequal; (2) those which compare equal must always do so; (3) for best performance, objects should compare equal if those constraints permit. The best way I see to express such a relation is via virtual function.